# i want to call variables from one java class to different java class in android

Tags: java, android

Its like there are many class like Login.java, Updatedetails.java, Result.java etc.

Here is the java code for Login.java

```
package com.example.catxam;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



import com.example.catxam.JSONParser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Login extends Activity {

private EditText inputUserid, inputPassword, server;
TextView forgotPassword;
private Button b1;
public static String serve;



// Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String resp = "success";
    private static final String Flag = "flag";


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    inputUserid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username_edit);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.User_password);
    server = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serverSelection);

    forgotPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgotPassword);
    forgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent passForget = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ForgotPassword.class);
            startActivity(passForget);
        }
    });
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton); // login button


    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

                new CreateNewUser().execute();

            }
    });

}



    // this class is for the checking of the user login and password 
    //i.e. of first login and the next consecutive logins
    class CreateNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */

    protected void shradu() {
        //super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Failed Login");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    /**
     * Checking creditenials
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String user = inputUserid.getText().toString();
        String pswrd = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        serve = server.getText().toString();

    if (serve.equals("web"))
        serve = "glydenlewis.esy.es";
    else if (serve.equals("g"))
        serve = "192.168.1.4";
    else if (serve.equals("r"))
        serve = "192.168.0.100";
    else if (serve.equals("v"))
        serve = "192.168.0.100";
    else
        serve = "glydenlewis.esy.es";



        // URL to check username & password
final String url_check_user = "http://" + serve + "/catxam/android_check.php";  

// Building Parameters
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", user));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("psd", pswrd));


// getting JSON Object
// Note that create product url accepts POST method

// this try is to catch if server address is wrong  
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check_user,"POST", params);

// check log cat from response
Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

// check for success tag
try {
    int success = json.getInt(resp);
    int flag_ck = json.getInt(Flag);
    if (success == 1) {
        if (flag_ck == 0)
        {
            //First Time Login By User
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateDetails.class);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First Login, Please Update Your Details",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(i);
            finish();   // closing this screen  
        }
        else 
        {
        // successfully login
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        startActivity(i);
        finish();   // closing this screen
        }
    } else {
        // successfully login
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LogoStart.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();   // closing this screen
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return null;

    }

}
```

}

now for the UpdateDetails.java

```
 package com.example.catxam;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;


  import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
  import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
  import org.json.JSONException;
  import org.json.JSONObject;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.ProgressDialog;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.Toast;
  import android.view.Window;
  import android.view.WindowManager;

 public class UpdateDetails extends Activity  {

        EditText inputName;
        EditText inputAddress;
        EditText inputPassword;
        EditText confirmPassword;
        EditText inputEmailId, inputMobileno;
        // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String resp = "success";
        //private static final String Flag = "flag";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.updatedetails);

        // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
        inputAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAddress);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        confirmPassword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editConfirmPassword);
        inputEmailId=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2_emailid);
        inputMobileno=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1_mobile);

        // Create button
        Button update_details = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);

        // button click event
        update_details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (inputPassword == confirmPassword){
                // updating user in background thread
                new UpdateUserDetails().execute();
                }
                else {
                    //Some Sort Of Alert Box
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Valid Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class UpdateUserDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UpdateDetails.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Updating User Details.. Please wait");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Updating User
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String address = inputAddress.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            String mobileno = inputMobileno.getText().toString();
            String emailid = inputEmailId.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", address));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile_no", mobileno));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email_id",emailid));

            final String url_user = "http://"+ Login.serve +"/catxam/android_update.php";

            // getting JSON Object
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_user,"POST", params);

            // check log cat from response
            Log.d("Update Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(resp);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully update user
                    Intent i = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unsuccessful Updation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Now my question is that as i have declared all the server option only in login.java, which can be accessed by other class as Login.serve.

so i just want to make it simple and save all the address in GlobalVariableCall.java. and then these address would be accessed by different classes.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass variables thru one activity to an other with the intent method wich is very simple...

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(firstActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("data", data); //Optional parameters or data to be send to the next activity
                    firstActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

in that case you declare the global variable in the firstActivity... and you can putExtras as you want those are the variables that you are sending to the next activity

or you can instanciate the global variable class but you will lose the value of the variable when passing it thru one class to another...

Answer (score 0):

> i want to make a single class called as GlobalVariableCall where i am
>   declaring few variables such as public static Sting server.

So you have declared:

```
class GlobalVariableCall 
{
   public static String server="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634112/i-want-to-call-variables-from-one-java-class-to-different-java-class-in-android";
}
```

Then You  can call this server variable from other Activity say **Login.java** like this:

```
OnCreate()
{
   ............
..............

   String abc = GlobalVariableCall.server; // In this way abc will get the value of server.
}
```

Comment: My question, remains the same. its just that i have multiple server address. Like

Comment: I just don't get you what you really want to do?

Comment: Actually Login.java has a EditText where it take user input for server address. And to make this globally accessible i declared serve in GlobalVariableCall as public static serve.


but problem is that what if there are too many server running. So i want to make this part of code global so every server address could be accessed.
if (serve.equals("web"))
   serve = "glydenlewis.esy.es";
  else if (serve.equals("g"))
   serve = "192.168.1.4";
  else if (serve.equals("r"))
   serve = "192.168.0.100";
  else if (serve.equals("v"))
   serve = "192.168.0.100";
  else
   serve = "glydenlewis.esy.es";

Comment: (Actually Login.java has a EditText where it take user input for server address. Thats fine. And to make this globally accessible i declared serve in GlobalVariableCall as public static serve. - Why d o you want to make it global?  but problem is that what if there are too many server running. What does that mean too many server running? Can you display the flow of your project?

Comment: Just try to edit the question in a properly understood way & Post your Code and Xml files. So one can understand your question properly and reply accordingly.

Comment: I edited the question, now it's more clear. It seems that you have 2 server variables!! Why not only one?!